# How To get Id from the url Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

My question may look simple but I'm stuck in this problem for a while.

Code Controller:

```
[Route("api/ReceiptOrders/{receiptOrderNo}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReceiptPositionsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{orderNo}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostReceiptOrderPositions(
        [FromBody] IEnumerable<ReceiptPositionForCreationDto> receiptPositions)
    {
        var receiptOrder = await _repositoryManager.ReceiptOrder.GetReceiptOrderByOrderNoAsync(receiptOrderNo, false);
        //More code here...
    }
}
```

URL: `https://localhost:7164/api/ReceiptOrders/RO-20220731-4/ReceiptPositions`

my question is: how to get the ReceiptOrderNo(RO-20220731-4 in this case)?
I need it to fill  "GetReceiptOrderByOrderNoAsync" method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the template entry by adding another parameter in your method. In addition, remove the template from the method's attribute. A method's template is appended to the class's template, so what you currently have won't match.

```
[Route("api/ReceiptOrders/{receiptOrderNo}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReceiptPositionsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost] // <--- no template
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostReceiptOrderPositions(
        [FromRoute] string receiptOrderNo,  // <---- new parameter
        [FromBody] IEnumerable<ReceiptPositionForCreationDto> receiptPositions)
    {
        // ... use "receiptOrderNo"
    }
```

You don't *need* `[FromRoute]`, but I think it's a good idea as it makes it explicit where the value should be read from, instead of accidently read from a Query String or another source.